# compare two items in list, and then split into smaller list at index

Tags: c#

So i have a list of locations. I need to split the list if the distance between each location is greater than say 30.

I can loop through the list and get the distance between each location, i am just not sure what the best approach is to split the list, i have read answers that break the list into chunks with a set size, but in my case the size could be variable depending on the distance between locations.

This could be really simple and i just cant see it. What i have so far is below, the code is pretty straightforward in comparing the two items, its purely splitting the list i am stuck at. Currently my code would not include all the items from the original list, it would exclude the items before the first GetRange.

```
var unkownSegments = grouped.Where(x => x.ActivityType == null);

foreach (var group in unkownSegments)
{
   var tempLists = new List<List<LocationResult>>();
   for (int i = 0; i < group.Items.Count - 1; i++)
   {
      var point1 = group.Items[i];
      var point2 = group.Items[i + 1];

      var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(point1.Lat, point1.Long);
      var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(point2.Lat, point2.Long);

      var distance = sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);

      if(distance > 30)
      {
         var tempList = group.Items.GetRange(i, group.Items.Count - i);
         tempLists.Add(tempList);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a range (using `GetRange()` method), you need to know where it begins and where it ends. If distance between `Item[i]` and `Item[i+1]` is greater then `30`, you know the *end*, because that *end* is at index `i`. But you don't know the *beginning* (of course, you know it for the first range - it's `0`), because *beginning* depends on the *end* of previous range. So you need to introduce new variable (it's called `rangeStart` in my example bellow), that will contain such information. It starts with value `0` (that's where first range always begins) and then update it's value whenever you add new range (next range will always start at index `i+1`).

After the `for` loop finishes, some points will remain. So need to add them points as the last range. Whole method can then look like this:

```
var unkownSegments = grouped.Where(x => x.ActivityType == null);

foreach (var group in unkownSegments)
{
   var tempLists = new List<List<LocationResult>>();

   //This variable keeps track of the beginning of the next range
   var rangeStart = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < group.Items.Count - 1; i++)
   {
      var point1 = group.Items[i];
      var point2 = group.Items[i + 1];

      var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(point1.Lat, point1.Long);
      var eCoord = new GeoCoordinate(point2.Lat, point2.Long);

      var distance = sCoord.GetDistanceTo(eCoord);

      if(distance > 30)
      {
         var tempList = group.Items.GetRange(rangeStart, i - rangeStart + 1);
         tempLists.Add(tempList);
         rangeStart = i + 1;//Next range will begin on the following item
      }
   }

   if (group.Items.Count - rangeStart > 0)
   {
      //Add all remainging (not added yet) points as the last range.
      var tempList = group.Items.GetRange(rangeStart, group.Items.Count - rangeStart);
      tempLists.Add(tempList);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i was looking for.